GNU Screen copy/paste not working
In GNU screen mode, the copy mode seems to work but when I try to paste, it is pasting something from a copy command I did a long time ago (same contents are pasted even after re-opening screen in a new terminal or after a linux reboot).
Not sure if there is an issue in storing copy contents to register, or if some mapping is causing issue in the paste command.

I don't think GNU screen copies to the system clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111548/how-to-copy-the-gnu-screen-copy-buffer-to-the-clipboard

True. I'm not sure why I'm unable to paste though.
Is there a way to find the original mapping command which is the equivalent of "Ctrl+a+]" so that I can force the mapping in .screenrc?

How do you paste? I'm guessing you are pasting from the system clipboard somehow...

I'm using "Ctrl+a+[" to enter copy mode and "Ctrl+a+]" for paste. I've also tried to enter copy mode with "Ctrl+a+Esc" in case that makes a difference.
